# python error: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have got a problem with my code. I'm trying to use the variable `channels_index` under the loop to get each element from the list once at a time without keep looping but I have got an error: `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`

When I try this:

```
dbconnect = con.cursor()
dbconnect.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM programs")
x = dbconnect.fetchone()[0]

for channels_range, total_channels in enumerate(xrange(1, x + 1, 69), 1):
    pass
channels_index = range(0, channels_range)   # count how many channels I have got

for ind, row in enumerate(programs):
    program = row[1].encode('ascii'), str(row[2]), str(row[3])
    title = row[1].encode('ascii')
    program_start_date = str(row[2])
    program_end_date = str(row[3])

    program_height = 33
    program_gap = 3
    position_top = programs_top + channels_index * (program_height + program_gap + 1.5)
```

The error are highlight on this line:

```
position_top = programs_top + channels_index * (program_height + program_gap + 1.5)
```

Here is a list of elements:

```
18:22:32 T:3680  NOTICE: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

I'm connecting to a database to fetch the data from every 69 rows to counts on how many rows I have got in a range. I can't put the value of `17` in the line for that code `position_top = programs_top + value`, because I won't know how many 69 rows I have got in a database.

Can you please help me how I can use the variable `channels_index` under the loop to fetch each element from a list once at a time without keep looping?

Comment: `channels_index` is a *list*, but `(program_height + program_gap + 1.5)` produces a float. What did you expect to happen there?

Comment: I'm not following what you are trying to achieve, actually.If you are trying to loop over every 69 rows of `programs` there are better methods to do so, like [What is the most "pythonic" way to iterate over a list in chunks?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/434287)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes `channels_index` is a list, but what I'm expect them to fetch the value from the list once at a time, example: fetch the value `0` to output them, then fetch the next value `1` to output them and so on.

Comment: Presumably you want to *cycle* over those values? So loop from `0` to `16` then back to `0`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters No I want to cycle those values that start from `0` to `16` and not to go back to `0`.

Comment: @Rob your code would create a `NameError` since you never define `programs_top` Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your error along with the expected output. You've had several people guess at what you're trying to achieve and I guess they've all missed the question -- can you better-define your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to *cycle* through the values 0 through `channels_range`, then use a modulus:

```
channels_index = 0

for ...:
    channels_index = (channels_index + 1) % channels_range
```

This will increment `channels_index` to `1`, then `2`, all the way up to `channels_range - 1`, then go back to 0.

There is no need to produce a list of values up front here.

If you wanted to calculate 69 times 0, then 69 times 1, etc. counting up to 16, you can still calculate that simply from the row index:

```
for ind, row in enumerate(programs):
    channel_index = ind // 69
```

The row indices 0 through to 68, divided by 69 produce `0`. Indices 69 through to 137 give `1`,  etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for that, but no I want to cycle through the values from `0` to `16` without go back to `0`. Please can you change your code.

Comment: Thank you very much for that, but on my code it will start to cycle from 0 to 16 at the same time. I want to cycle the values `0` for 69 times before I go to the next values `1` and so on. How I can do that?

Comment: I want to cycle the values to make it 69 times like this: `0`, `0`,`0`,`0`,`0`,`0`,`0`,`0`,`0`,`0` until 69 times then cycle the next value to make it 69 times `1`, `1`,`1`,`1`,`1`,`1`,`1`,`1`,`1`,`1`..etc.

Comment: @Rob: What about itertools.repeat?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm waiting for your answer.

Comment: @Rob: ah, but I ran out of time; this is why you need to be clear in your question from the start what you expect. So you want to repeat `0` 69 times, then `1`, all the up to `16`?

Comment: @Rob: or perhaps there is no upper limit, you just want to count out each 69 rows?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes of course I do. Can you update your code please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get exactly what you're asking, but if you're trying to grab indices from `channels_index` one at a time, why not just add it to your `for` loop?

```
# same as above...
for (ind, row), ch_idx in zip(enumerate(programs), channels_index):
   # continue on as before
   position_top = programs_top + ch_idx * (program_height + program_gap + 1.5)
```